# How to set up a global prefix and suffix used in each error field in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

In Struts, you can confire a global prefix and suffix in a resource bundle file. Something like:

```
errors.prefix=<div class="error">
errors.suffix=</div>
```

So <div class="error"> will be added before each <html:errors and </div> will be added after each one.

So how can i get the same effect by using Spring form tags <form:errors ?

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, but you have to implement a custom MessageSource

```
public class CustomMessageSource extends ResourceBundleMessageSource {

    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        if(code.startsWith("typeMismatch"))
            return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;

        if(code.startsWith("errors"))
            return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;

        return super.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage, locale);
    }

    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        if(code.startsWith("typeMismatch"))
            return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;

        if(code.startsWith("errors"))
            return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;

        return super.getMessage(code, args, locale);
    }

    public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        String [] errors = resolvable.getCodes();
        for(String error: errors) {
            if(error.startsWith("typeMismatch"))
                return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;

            if(error.startsWith("errors"))
                return this.prefix + super.getMessage(resolvable, locale) + this.suffix;
        }

        return super.getMessage(resolvable, locale);
    }

}
```

Now you have to define your custom MessageSource

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="br.com.some.CustomMessageSource">
    <property name="prefix" value="<div class=\"error\">"/>
    <property name="suffix" value="</div>"/>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
             <value>messages</value>
             <value>errors</value>
        </list>
    </property name="basenames">
</bean>
```

regards,

Answer (score 2):

Why would you? Spring renders errors inside a `<span>` tag whose css class you specify via `cssClass` attribute of `<spring:errors>`. You can then style it however you want via CSS.

`<span>` itself is [customizable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.errors) too, apparently (I've just looked, never needed to change it myself):

```
<spring:errors element="div" cssClass="errorBox" path="..."/>
```

would wrap errors in `<div class="errorBox"></div>`

Comment: Can you explain what you need it for? See my edit - you can very much do the `div` like you've specified in your question. If that's not enough (if you need **several** enclosed tags) I suppose your options are DOM manipulation or extending Spring's ErrorsTag and writing your own version.

Comment: There are no Struts-like global settings for Spring's errors tag.

Comment: @ChssPly76 If i can set up a global settings, i avoid set up it in each form:errors

Comment: I understand, but "global" settings do not exist. Once again, though, `<span>` + CSS has always been enough for me. It's rather trivial to extend `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag` to add "global" settings if you really need them.

Comment: @Arthur, ChssPly76 can't make it work if Spring didn't build it in!